# concerning updating img element classes in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic, element

I recently came across a website called Google Gravity and I thought that would be cool to implement on my homepage. After searching around I found that their Javascript could be used quite easily. I saw a sample webpage coded from it which can be see here. http://ankitpatel.info/mygravity/

What I want to do is create a internal counter variable in PHP so that every nth time the user goes to the 'Home' page, say every 5th time, the home page gets the gravity effect that would be all the divs, images, maybe header texts. Looks like fun.

So I decided that before coding it into my existing site I would get it right first with the example page and that way I could have it all ready and bug free. Well here is the code that I got from the above webpage and some modifications I made.

In the original code the 4 img have the class='box2d' hard coded into them.

On my homepage they would not have that class attached initially. Once the PHP counter reads the 5th view, I would call a Javascript function Gravity() that would go through all the divs and attach the extra class to each in order to get the effect.. am I correct, is this the best way?

I tried running the following but it does not seem to work. However if I manually put class='box2d' to each  it works.

I appreciate all responses to this matter. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bigger Brands - Bigger Gravity (Thanks to Google Gravity js)</title>
<script src="mygravity/ga.js" async="" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body style="position: static;"onload="getImages()">

<div id="content">
        <img src='mygravity/images/facebook-logo.jpg'/>
    <img src='mygravity/images/google.jpg'/>
    <img src='mygravity/images/twitter.png'/>
    <img src='mygravity/images/microsoft-logo.png'/>
</div>

<script src="mygravity/api" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="mygravity/defaulten.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="mygravity/gravityscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function getImages(){ 

    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].className += " box2d";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The gravity script finds all tags with the class box2d when it initializes. If you add these classes after initialization you have to run the following after adding the classes.

```
init();
run();
```

Comment: Could you give me a small helpful example where I put that and how to write it? I am just recently grasping JS.